# Why does s[s[3]] = '1' when char *s = "123"?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, c-strings

```
char* s = "123";
std::cout << s[s[3]] << std::endl; // prints 1
std::cout << s[3] << std::endl; // prints nothing?
```

I tried running the following snippet and the first print statement outputs `1` while the second outputs (seemingly) nothing. What is going on when the pointer is dereferenced using the length of the char pointer array here?

Comment: `s[3]` is zero. `s[0]` is '1'.

Comment: @S.M. Why is it zero? It's not printing zero for me.

Comment: Zero is not '0'.

Comment: `"123"` is actually a _4_ character array because it's null-terminated. So `s[3]` is `'\0'`, which  can convert to the integer `0` so `s[s[3]]` is `s[0]` is `'1'`.

Comment: To be more precise, a literal string like `"123"` is a four-element ***constant*** array of characters. Which means you should use `const char* s` to point to such strings. Your compiler should really warn you about this.

Comment: Also, try printing `static_cast<int>(s[3])` instead. It should print the integer value `0` (which is different from the character `'0'`). However, do *not* try to use anything from index `4` and onward, as that's out of bounds and will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `std::cout << +s[3] << std::endl;` will print `0`.

Comment: To expand on an earlier comment: Zero is not `'0'`. Forty-eight is `'0'`. *If you don't believe this, assign `48` to a `char` variable then stream that variable to `std::cout`.*

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you are using the *value of the character at index 3* (`s[3]`) to index the string again. But in any case, the key point here is that you're using a `char` to index an array. This means that the `char` is used as a number, the conversion happening most likely using the ASCII character encoding.

The reason you're getting nothing printed out when you print `s[3]` is because `s` is a character array with length 4, and the last character is the null terminator. Null meaning the number 0. The null terminator identifies the end of the string. But it is not a *printable character*, because it is not meant to be printed. It doesn't have a gliph associated with it, so you don't get anything printed.

Of course, you can see now that `s[s[3]]` is nothing but `s[0]`, which is the character "1".

Comment: ASCII has nothing to do with the conversion here; the code would do the same thing if the compiler used, say, EBCDIC. The value of `s[3]` is `'\0'`, which is a `char` whose value is 0.

Comment: No. The character encoding has no effect on what this code does.

Comment: I have no idea what your point is. This question and its answer have nothing to do with character encodings. You might as well be reciting that `int` often has 32 bits, but can be smaller or larger. It's true, but it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: `’\0’` has the value 0 regardless of the encoding. The `\0` is an octal escape sequence; it says hat the character value is 0.

Comment: Don't put words into my mouth. I think of a character as a character; I think of `char` as a numeric type, because that's what it is. After `char ch = 42;`, `ch` holds the value 42. After `char ch = '\0';`, `ch` holds the value 0. After `char ch = 'x';`, `ch` holds a value that depends on the character encoding. Again (and, I hope, for the last time), the character encoding has nothing to do with the value of `'\0'`.

Comment: Fine. There you go.